# Why is my Array modifier rotating my object at an offset angle?

Tags: modifiers

I have created a button and i want to rotate the button in circular way. But the button shape should be same shape. I have added array and empty to rotate. I got this result.

[image]

[image]

Or with the array i want it to bend or twist in circular way

[image]

But i want to rotate the button in same shape. Near by near but the angle to be same. As show below.

[image]

There should be no space between them. Like the array no space between and bend or twist circular shape it should get the shape.

[image]

Any suggestion or help how it will work. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the object needs to distort in order to leave no gaps, maybe a regular relative-offset array, given a Curve modifier, would suit better?

[image]

Oops.. or this, if you <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>180</kbd> in edit mode..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution got this result final render https://imgur.com/a/8Nldwwu

Comment: @atek ....love it. Great fun.

Answer (score 4):

You should line up your petals(?) to the circle origin center. Do it in edit mode will be faster with visual feedback.

[image]

You can line up these point using pivot or 3D cursor.

The modifier use that *empty* as a pivot point to rotate your object to create next duplicated mesh. You need to keep the button center line line up with that pivot point to do the effect you described.

You can choose *anything* to line up with it, try it yourself to find the best position you want.

Comment: sorry did not get can u plz explain in detail. And my both the petals are side by side black and white why u separated it. Thanks

Comment: It seems a little unbalance with them so i separate them. If you want them line up with the center together, line up it by the overlapping line between buttons.

Comment: Will what i need its im not getting it. With the array i want to bend or twist the mesh in the curve direction. https://imgur.com/a/Vao5GB5

Comment: There should be no space or gap between them, when bend or rotate or twisted. It should be like array continuous. Without space and bend and twist. https://imgur.com/a/Ej9kbhl